# Non-symmetric $A^T=A$

Tags: matrices, definition

Wikipedia says that symmetric matrices are square ones, which have the property $A^T=A$. This assumes that one can have non-square $A^T=A$ and, because it does not satisfy the first property of symmetry, it is not symmetric. So, there can be non-symmetric $A^T=A$ matrices and the definition is right. Is it right? Or, definition is redundant and misleading, and it is better to define a symmetric matrix by single $A^T=A$ property and symmetric matrix squareness follows from symmetry rather than defines symmetry? The question in short: should I say that symmetric matrix is square, when define it?

Comment: When transposing matrix changes its dimensionality, if it's not square. You can't compare for equality matrices that have different dimensionality.

Comment: Symmetric matrices are matrices that have the property that $A^T = A$, and all such matrices are square anyway (by counting rows and columns). The wikipedia definition is correct. Don't assume that, just because the word "square" is used, there must be non-square examples too - the word is redundant here, and is included just for clarity.

Comment: @Val: Reading mathematics is different to reading prose, and it is a separate skill that you learn, because mathematicians write in a certain way. The statement you have quoted is neither misleading nor confusing. It is precise and correct, and says nothing at all about non-square matrices with the property that $A^T = A$. In particular, it doesn't say whether they exist or not - you may try to work this out for yourself if you want to, but that's not what the definition is trying to get you to do.

Comment: Pure mathematics certainly seeks for economy in definition and proof. But teaching definitions and proofs to people who aren't natural pure mathematicians is a different thing altogether, and giving people new to the subject, or less confident, more to hold onto is pedagogically productive. When meeting a symmetric matrix in an application we help someone to remember "we're talking about square matrices here" and that may be what they need to keep them on the right track.

Comment: I have removed quite a bit of chaff from this thread. Be nice, and stay on topic. @Val: I should not that you seem to be coming off as quite abrasive against users who are trying to help you. If you continue in this manner, there might be none left willing to help.

Comment: @mixedmath I have asked question for everybody. Everybody must believe that there are non-square $A^T=A$ matrices when they hear the Wikipedia definition.

Comment: @Val I was not trying to be insulting in that comment, and I don't see how it can be read as such. I was reacting to the fact that you seemed more interested in pushing an idea than in exploring the pedagogical implications of one definition over the other. You came with an absolutist philosophy that seemed to indicate less that you wanted to ask a question and more that you wanted to promote a point of view. It's possible that you were open to debate, but it hasn't appeared to be. (I could actually go with either definition. I just don't think one is better or worse.)

Comment: "Everybody must believe... when they hear the Wikipedia definition." is again absolutist. The definition doesn't imply that such things can exist. It simply doesn't say a thing about the existence of non-square examples. (It actually doesn't imply even the existence of symmetric examples.)

Comment: @Val: Unlike in standard written English, the statement "x is true" does *not* hint that "not-x is false" in mathematics. Mathematics must be read literally and exactly as it was written. (There are also very good arguments for including the word "square" in the definition - for example, it's not clear what the equals sign between $A$ and $A^T$ even *means* unless we already *know* that they have the same size, so that has been hardwired into the definition.)

Comment: 99% of the people learning linear algebra are not mathematicians, but engineers and computer scientists. Most of these people would never think, "Can there be non-square solutions to $A^t=A$"? And then the question becomes, "So what if they think there might be such examples?" How does that harm their learning of linear algebra? Most people smart and curious enough to ask the question are smart enough, as you were, to figure out that there were no such things, and that the definition is redundant. The fact that they don't exist is, though, a completely uninteresting result.

Comment: They are people like me and the definition you defend makes us thinking about such things. What if the people who read Wikipedia decide to edit it a little? They are not matematicians. But, to be correct, when they want to refer to symmetric matrix and briefly tell what it is, they think if it is enough to mention that $A^T=A$ or they need necessarily state that matrix is square? Will it be a big mistake if they omit the requirement of squareness? 99% of linear algebra students are not matematicians. Should wikipedia be written by matematicians?

Comment: I do not understand the close-votes (or even the downvotes). There is a genuine question here! You are voting on a question, not on the OPs understanding of a concept!

Comment: @Billy Saying that dimensions are equal is not sufficient to explain what equality means. The logic would be: since fulfilling equality $A^T=A$ implies that matrix is square, there cannot be object $A$ that is both $A^T=A$ and not square. This eliminates the question I have asked!

Comment: @Val: I would say that the answer to the question "is A = B?", where A and B are matrices are different sizes, is not "yes" or "no", but rather "the question doesn't make sense, because you haven't told me how to compare these objects". In that sense, it is absolutely necessary to know that your two matrices have the same size before putting an equals sign between them. You can formulate mathematics differently, if you want, and define the answer to be "no, because their sizes are different". It doesn't really matter.

Comment: How do you know that definition says nothing about non-square matrices? It is at least ambigous. It might be incomplete. Then indeed, it does not say anything about the general rectangular matrices. In case it is complete (which I believe is true) the stipulation about squares assumes that there exist non-square $A^T=A$ by http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_that_proves_the_rule. In either case you must ask "are non-square $A^T=A$ symmetric?" Everybody must ask my question. I call it logic and rigor. Do you label it "dictatorship" to close as US empire closes disobedient regimes?

Comment: @user1729 thaks for shaming the exprets. I was sure they will close as not real question as the question was very clear. This always happens with very clear questions. Now, Billy, matrix equality is perfectly defined. I have checked all top google definitionas and they all agree on equality is specified for unequally sized matrices. And, if it really does not matter, then, please, stop grounding your argument on that.

Comment: A definition (e.g. of the term "symmetric matrix") can never imply a theorem (such as "there exist non-square matrices with $A^T=A$").

Comment: Good point, Hagen. This also confused me when others started to push the idea that redundancy is ok in the definition. It is not good not because of the reason of minimality (which is also the case) but we need the minimal definition right because if we include postulate of squareness into the definition then we cannot prove it saying that squareness follows from symmetry. That is why I wanted to define the simmetry by $A^T=A$ alone, saying that it is a better definition, causing less confusion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you consider that if $A$ is a $n$-by-$m$ matrix, then $A^T$ is a $m$-by-$n$ matrix, so it follows that if $A$ = $A^T$ then a necessary condition is that $n=m$ as the matrices need to have the same number of rows/columns if they are equal, so $A$ must be a square matrix.

Answer (score 5):

This is what Wiki says:

"In linear algebra, a symmetric matrix is a square matrix that is equal to its transpose".

Now, it **certainly** follows from the definition that $\,A\,$ is symmetric if $\,A^t=A\,$, and from this it follows at once that $\,A\,$ has to be square, but mentioning this in the definition above can hardly be confusing: reduntant, yes.

For example, you can check that many algebra books define a *group* as "a non-empty set with an binary operation...", and this "non-empty" thingy **also** is redudant as it follows at once from the axiom on the *existence* of a unity element...etc.

Things like the above ones, besides being a little boring and futile to discuss a lot about, are designed mostly to avoid misunderstandings from beginner students. That's all, imfho.

Comment: I have explained you how it is confusing. In order to avoid confusion for beginners, you could simply list the squareness as the first property of symmetry. Otherwise, student is right to think that $A^T=A$ is not sufficient to establish the symmetry. Why do not you want to see the problem and, along with others, argue for confusion as clarity?

Comment: @Val, what I think you've explained is what **you** find confusing (or misleading) in Wiki's definition, and I tried above to explain you and all why I don't think that is misleading, though I agree it is redundant. You wrote both these characteristics *redundant and misleading* together, as if one **must** appear with the other. I don't think this is right and, of course, I don't think this is so in this particular case.

Comment: I have explained it objectively. If you do not know that m=n follows from $A^T=A$, you _must_ assume that there are m≠n matrices, which satisfy $A^T=A$. In math, you must assume all the alternatives. So, _all students_ will fall into the assumption that I did. So, it is not my, it is everybodies obligation to suppose the existence of the objects that I described. It is therefore unfair to argue that it is my personal fault and I am special and definition is ok.

Comment: @Val, I've already written in my answer above that I agree the definition is *redundant*...no discussion about that! Now, apparently you find that "misleading", too, and I tried to explain why I believe it is *not* misldeading.

Comment: The problem is that your "good pedagogy" is drilling of facts. It is bad pedagogy, objectively, since it raises such question as mine and does not teach the relationship between facts. Just saying that square follows from $A^T=A$ is simple and ties pieces together. By merely drilling of fragmentary, unrelated facts you neither produce masses of cattle rather than thinkers nor drilling simplifies material comprehension. I cannot stop you calling my approach "the absolutist pedagogy".

Answer (score 1):

No, if $A$ is an $n\times m$ matrix then $A^T$ is an $m\times n$ matrix, so if $A$ is not square, then $n\neq m$ and hence $A^T$ has different dimensions to $A$ and hence can't be compared with $A$.

In that sense, $A^{T}=A$ implies $A$ square, but it also implies comparing matrices of different dimensions, which is something to avoid. (It's not technically wrong to say $A\neq B$ when $A,B$ are different dimensions, but it can cause confusion.)

Comment: In a sufficiently sophisticated programming language, it is possible to arrange for matrices of different dimensions to have different "types", so that they cannot be compared. I don't know how this sort of thing is done in mathematics, but intuitively it makes sense to me to say that matrices of different dimensions are simply not equal, while a sentence like $S = M$, where $S$ is a set of integers and $M$ is a matrix of reals, just doesn't make any sense.

Comment: In mathematics, you define a matrix rigorously via set theory, and the sets are simply distinct in that case, so they are not equal as sets. But, as you say, there is a matter of types, which was why I suggested that it could cause confusion to write that. @dfeuer