# How should I define symmetric matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, logic, definition

"A matrix A is a symmetric matrix if its transpose $A^T$ = $A$." This is my definition.

"A **square** matrix A is a symmetric matrix if its transpose $A^T$ = $A$." This is the textbook definition.

I understand that only square matrices can be symmetric, but I figured it would be all right to cut out the "square", as satisfying the equation $A^T$ = $A$ would ensure it is a square matrix.

So why can't I omit the "square"? (An error I was sternly reminded of.)

Any better definitions would also be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., [basic help on mathjax notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), and [equation editing how-to](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773)

Comment: If you want to get $A^T$, type \$A^T\$

Comment: I think you can remove the "square" since if it is not a square matrix then $A^T$ cannot be equal to $A$.

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/428499/non-symmetric-at-a?rq=1)

Comment: what with $A^T-A=0$ if matrices are not square   ?

Comment: @widawensen For the operation $A^T$ - $A$ to be carried out, $A^T$ and $A$ must be of the same order, which in turn implies $A$ must be square. The answers were good in explaining them.

Answer (score 6):

I think both definitions are perfectly valid (and mathematically equivalent), however I prefer the textbook definition.

The textbook definition makes a distinction between two cases. Consider the matrices  $$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}, B=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}.$$

In some sense, the textbook definition says different things about them.

1. For $A$, the textbook definition tells you that $A$ is not a symmetric matrix, because $A^T\neq A$.
2. For $B$, the textbook definition tells you that $B$ is not a symmetric matrix because the concept of symmetric matrices is incompatible with non-square matrices.

I like this additional clarity in the definition. It makes it clear that $B$ is not symmetric because, in a sense, it doesn't even make sense to ask whether $B$ is symmetric.

Comment: Or could you even say $B$ was symmetric after the first definition, since the vector $B=\begin{bmatrix} 1\\0\end{bmatrix}$ is the same as $B=1\vec e_x+0\vec e_y$ which is the same as $B^T=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: @klunkean I disagree. There is no interpretation of mathematical symbols that supports the position $B=B^T$. You just handwaved yourself into a contradiction.

Comment: That's why I posed it as a question. I think the notion of transposing a vector irritates me in general. It does not make any sense to me, since $B$ and $B^T$ are completely the same object. Take 1 in $x$ direction and 0 in $y$ direction. I think it only exists to be able to apply rules for matrix multiplication.

Comment: @klunkean the best way to think about these is as linear transformations, because linear transformations are functions, so they don't care what is a row/column vector, neither do linear maps care about in what funny manner you decide to arrange a bunch of numbers. Having said this, there is a widely agreed upon convention on how to REPRESENT a linear map $f:V \to W$ as an array of numbers after a choice of basis. And once we agree upon a certain convention, a matrix and its transpose are completely different objects, because they are the matrix representations of completely different maps.

Comment: I completely agree and that's the interpretation I stuck with ever since having struggled with perceived ambiguities after my first undergraduate course on linear algebra. The fact that this representation of numbers in a shelf is a convention wasn't emphasized enough I guess.

Answer (score 2):

You can say that an $m\times n$ matrix $A=(a_{ij})$ is symmetric if, and only if, $\forall i=1\ldots m, \forall j=1 \ldots n, a_{ij}=a_{ji}$, but you would encounter the problem of what to do if $a_{ji}$ is undefined. Accepting that $a_{ij} = \mathrm{undefined}$ is false, you could use that definition.

But anyway, your definition is OK. Trying to build something else is overcomplicating things!

Answer (score -1):

Given an $m\times n$ matrix $A=(a_{ij})$ and a $k\times l$ matrix $B=(b_{uv})$ with entries in a commutative ring $R$.

The matrices $A,B$ are equal if the mappings $f:[m]\times [n]\rightarrow R: (i,j)\mapsto a_{ij}$ and $g:[k]\times [l]\rightarrow R: (u,v)\mapsto b_{uv}$ are equal. Equality of maps means equality of the corresponding relations (sets).

Practically, this means that $A,B$ are equal if $A,B$ have the same size $(m=k,n=l)$ and for each pair $(i,j)\in[m]\times [n]$, $a_{ij}=b_{ij}$.

Well, if $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix, then the transposed $A^T$ is an $n\times m$ matrix.
By the above definition, the equality $A=A^T$ means that $m=n$ and $a_{ij}=a_{ji}$.

Comment: This greatly supports OP that you don't need the square statement because it is implied. Thus it does not answer the question imo.